# What is it called to argue in favor of something one actually opposes

Tags: terminology, argument-structure

What is it called when someone pretends to support ideas they oppose in order to ridicule those ideas and cast them in a negative light to others?

For example Stephen Colbert used to argue in favor of very Conservative political ideologies. But anyone watching knows that his true feelings are the polar opposite to those of his onscreen tv persona.

Or in a less obvious example: There was an advertising campaign a while back supporting the closing of public libraries and the removal of books to make way for something else. The people responsible for the campaign were really trying to garner public interest in saving these libraries by playing the part of the villain. They relied on the public to take an active interest in saving something by pretending to seek its demise.

Whether an obvious mockery of a position as in the first example or a more cunningly executed maneuver as in the second, is this type of argumentative / persuasion tactic known as something specific? And if so what is it called?

Comment: Well the Stephen Colbert example is one of *satire* or *caricature*.

Answer (score 4):

They are possibly playing ***devil's advocate***:

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devil%27s_advocate):

> In common parlance, a **devil's advocate** is someone who, given a
>   certain point of view, *takes a position they do **not** necessarily
>   agree with* (or simply an alternative position from the accepted
>   norm), *for the sake of debate or to explore the thought further*. In
>   taking this position, the individual taking on and playing the devil's
>   advocate role *seeks to engage others in an argumentative discussion*
>   process. The purpose of such a process is typically *to test the
>   quality of the original argument* and *identify weaknesses*, if
>   possible, in its structure, and to *use such information to either
>   improve or abandon the original, opposing position*. It can also refer
>   to someone who *takes a **stance** that is seen as **unpopular or
>   unconventional***, but is ***actually*** another way of **arguing a
>   much more conventional stance**.

From [dictionary.cambridge.org](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/devil-s-advocate):

> *noun* ​ someone who pretends, in an argument or discussion, to be against an idea or plan that a lot of people support, in order to make
>   people discuss and consider it in more detail:
>
> I ***don't*** really believe all that - I was *just **playing devil's advocate***.

From [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/devil-s-advocate):

> *noun*
>   1. a person who *advocates an opposing or unpopular cause* for the sake of argument or *to expose it to a thorough examination*.
>
> For example, My role in the campaign is to *play **devil's advocate*** to
>   each new policy before it's introduced to the public.

From [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/devil's%20advocate):

> a person who expresses an opinion that disagrees with others so that
>   there will be an interesting discussion about some issue
>
> Teachers often *play **devil's advocate*** to provoke discussion in the
>   classroom.

Answer (score 2):

This is perhaps more relevant to the example involving the bookshop and less to that involving the politician, but consider the term *reverse psychology*.

> **Reverse psychology** *noun*
>   The principle or practice of encouraging a behaviour by counter-intuitive means, such as advocating its opposite.
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/reverse-psychology?q=reverse%20psychology)

Answer (score 1):

To be ***[two-faced](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/two-faced)*** is an expression close to you are describing:

> - marked by deliberate deceptiveness especially by pretending one set of feelings and acting under the influence of another; "she was a deceitful scheming little thing".

(The Free Dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

I think that **sophistry** fits, because of the deception it indicated by its usage;

> **sophistry**
>
> Pronunciation: /ˈsɒfɪstri/  NOUN (plural sophistries)
>
> [MASS NOUN]
>   1. The use of clever but false arguments, especially with the intention of deceiving: *trying to argue that I had benefited in any way from the disaster was pure sophistry*
>
> 1.1 [COUNT NOUN] A fallacious argument.
>
> ([ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sophistry))

Answer (score 0):

The type of argument and persuasion you describe is not irony. Irony is

> Speaking in such a way as to imply the contrary of what one says, often for the purpose of derision, mockery, or jest.

([*Silva Rhetoricae*, "irony"](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/I/irony.htm))

Satire, and parody in the service of satire, often employs thematic, topical and figural irony in mocking, deriding, ridiculing, or otherwise seeking to expose social ills and promote more widespread awareness of them.

Yet the vain posturing of Colbert and the pedestrian, foreordained failure of an ad campaign intended to promote libraries by recommending their destruction cannot judiciously be compared to such outstanding works as Petronius's *Satyricon*, Swift's *A Modest Proposal*, Huxley's *Brave New World*, and Bradbury's *Farenheit 451*. What is irony in the latter timeless works is in the former ephemeral media merely clownish and feeble joshing.

So no, it's not ironic to argue in favor of what you oppose, nor is it ironic to argue in opposition to what you favor. Such arguments, in contemporary treatments, are better described as trivial persiflage, frivolous chaffing, bantering raillery, or blunt sarcasm, than sharp and cutting **irony**.

Comment: I suppose we could list all the things this type of argument is not. For instance, It's also not a toaster. But then that hardly seems productive. I simply wanted to know if this type of argument had a specific name. But thank you for the cynical vocabulary lesson comparing the things you like to the things I listed as examples to illustrate a question. Now I have to return the Stephen Colbert box set and cutlery kit I bought as your Christmas gift. But I guess I should have asked for a list of things you don't want rather than a list of the things you do. My mistake. Kind of ironic you know?

Comment: @user556068, the answer is ironic, and satirical. To make it plain: the type of argument you describe, and the persuasive technique, are respectively 'ironic' and 'irony'. Your confusion is understandable: irony often is confusing, and the more so the more layered it is.

Comment: ..  **{>_<}** I don't like change!! You were supposed to be a jerk... but you're.. just.... expletive.... I don't know what you are... maybe.. ah.. explicit expletive! You... tricked me! And now I'm the jerk! Jeez...I'm gonna go yell at the neighbor's kids and think about this little... whatever this was.. I'll be back..

Comment: @user556068, I'll be looking forward to that box set and cutlery kit, the latter of which I'll whet until the blunt edge of sarcasm reveals the micro-tome of irony driving it.